# I can't connect and upload to FTP by command line

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, ftp, automation

I can't succeed to connect and upload files to some ftp by BATCH file I made.

Also, I want to upload all files from this local directory.

Please your help!

Thanks.

**The code:**

```
@echo off
echo user username>> ftpcmd.dat
echo pass>> ftpcmd.dat
echo cd /public_html/reports/>> ftpcmd.dat
echo mput C:\automation\tests\HtmlReporter\*>> ftpcmd.dat
ftp -n -s:ftpcmd.dat myserver.com
del ftpcmd.dat
echo quit>> ftpcmd.dat
pause
disconnect
bye
```

**The error:**

```
 Connected to MYSERVER.com.
220---------- Welcome to Pure-FTPd [privsep] ----------
220-You are user number 23 of 500 allowed.
220-Local time is now 05:30. Server port: 21.
220-This is a private system - No anonymous login
220 You will be disconnected after 3 minutes of inactivity.
ftp> user USERNAME
331 UserUSERNAME OK. Password required

230-OK. Current restricted directory is /
230-111 files used (1%) - authorized: 10000 files
230 17049 Kbytes used (1%) - authorized: 1536000 Kb
ftp> prompt
Interactive mode Off .
ftp> cd /public_html/reports/
250 OK. Current directory is /public_html/reports
ftp> mput C:\automation\tests\HtmlReporter\*
Error opening local file C:\automation\tests\HtmlReporter\..
Error opening local file C:\automation\tests\HtmlReporter\...
200 PORT command successful
```

Comment: As you can see yourself, an authentication is failing. Can you connect with any other FTP client (even GUI) using the same username and password? Did you check FTP server log for reasons it rejects your username/password?

Comment: Yes sure. I've already succeed to connect this server by FileZilla!
Probably my code is wrong :/ 
@MartinPrikryl

Comment: You should mention such important information in your question! Also include FileZilla log file.

Comment: OK, I've added the log from FileZilla.
Please chack out my post again @MartinPrikryl

Comment: That's not a log. Go to *Edit > Settings > Logging*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at this line:

```
echo password >> ftpcmd.dat
```

This actually doesn't store `password` in the dat file but `password_` (_ is space). Try to remove spaces before `>>`:

@echo off

```
echo user username>> ftpcmd.dat
echo password>> ftpcmd.dat
echo /public_html/reports>> ftpcmd.dat
echo mput c:\workspace\automation\HtmlReporter\Test_Report.html>> ftpcmd.dat
echo quit>> ftpcmd.dat
ftp -n -s:ftpcmd.dat servernamet.com
del ftpcmd.dat
pause
disconnect
bye
```

Comment: Thanks a lot :) It works!
Can you please tell me how to upload all files from some local directory to specific location in my FTP server?
@MichaelS

Comment: Do not reuse the question for different problems. Please post a new question for for the new problem.

Comment: Martin PrikrylMartin is right, please post a new question. Btw: sorry, unfortunately I can't help you with the new issue :(

Comment: But, I've to wait 90min until my next question.. :(

Comment: Try to add `echo prompt>> ftpcmd.dat` just before the `echo mput C:\automation\tests\HtmlReporter\*>> ftpcmd.dat` line.

Comment: It seems like we are on the right way.. but actually it succeed to upload only one file from 15. and it receive error about theme in the cmd. please see my updated post. thanks a lot :) @MichaelS